# Unable to use Contact Picker

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming.
I am unable to invoke the contact picker from my activity.
I have referred to many tutorial,formatted my code accordingly but got no result.

The code for MainActivity.java is:-

```
    package com.example.intents;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater mi=getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void invokeForRes(View view)
    {
        Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contact.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(in, 1);
    }

}
```

Please help me.......
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the onActivityResult method.

Comment: Since i am an beginner firstly i am just trying to invoke the contact picker Activity.
Just doing it in steps.
@Yugesh

Comment: Contact picker will invoked or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`, not `Contact.Contacts.CONTENT_URI`. The latter was the Android 1.x contacts provider, and it was replaced by `ContactsContract` in Android 2.0, released in late 2009.

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain   a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.rotation.bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class RotationBundleDemo extends Activity {
  static final int PICK_REQUEST=1337;
  Button viewButton=null;
  Uri contact=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    viewButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        contact=data.getData();
        viewButton.setEnabled(true);
      }
    }
  }

  public void pickContact(View v) {
    Intent i=
        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(i, PICK_REQUEST);
  }

  public void viewContact(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contact));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if (contact != null) {
      outState.putParcelable("contact", contact);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    contact=state.getParcelable("contact");
    viewButton.setEnabled(contact != null);
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ConfigChange/Bundle))